# How to display data entered in one activity in another activity in list one by one in android?

Tags: java, android

`FirstActivity.java`

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Name = etName.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SecondActivity.class);
            // Create a bundle object
            intent.putExtra("NAME", Name);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

My `Second Activity.java` is as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String UName;
String iName;
ListView lvName;
Button btnBack;

Bundle savedInstanceState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    lvName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNames);
    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);


    UName=b.getString("NAME");


    list.add(UName);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvName.setAdapter(adapter);


    lvName.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();



            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ThirdActivity.class);
            // Create a bundle object
            intent.putExtra("ITEMNAME", item);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}
```

My problem is whenever I click on back button, activity is restarted. So that first item in list is overwritten by second item. I want to get the output as list(items one by one) in second activity, whatever the data I enter in first activity. How can I do this?

For example when I enter ABC in edittext its displaying the same data ABC in list.Its good.
But when I click on back button and again enter any data in edittext its not displaying the data as second item in list but it is over writing the first item.This is the thing I wanna get  to be solved...

Comment: on back button click call finish(); insted of restarting the MainActivity

Comment: Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to avoid overwritten of prev item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all items into intent in the first activity:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(ITEMS, list);
```

And then you can extract them from intent in the second activity:

```
List<String> items = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(ITEMS);
```

Comment: Ya I tried it,But its throwing null pointer exception at list.addAll(items);

Comment: @SwethaIT It means that `list` is `null` when you adding it to intent or you didn't add it to intent `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class)`

Comment: I used these lines    myList = b.getStringArrayList("NAME");
        list.addAll(myList);

Comment: @SwethaIT how you adding list to intent in the first activity?

Answer (score 0):

You Just have to create the global list somewhere in your app like you can create Singletone or Application Class where you have to store your username List.

In below code you have to update your arrayList in first activity and you have to get your nameList in SecondActivity

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static MySingleton _instance;
    private ArrayList<String> nameList;

    private MySingleton()
    {

    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

   public ArrayList<String> getNameList(){
      return nameList;
   }

    public void setNameList(ArrayList<String> nameList(){
       nameList = nameList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the extends Application class

```
public class MyGlobal extends Application {
public ArrayList<String> selectedAppsPackageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

for getting this in your activity

```
private MyGlobal mMyGlobal = (MyGlobal) getApplicationContext();
```

declare in manifest inside the Application Tag(give the path)

```
<application
android:name="com.afbb.lockaddicted.core.MyControlList"
..............
.........
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the names in the `FirstActivity` to shared preferences, with an id. Then retrieve those values in the `SecondActivity`. Also do not forget to clear the shared preferences when you destroy your `FirstActivity`.

**FirstActivity**

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText etName;
    private Button btnOk;
    private String name;
    private int id = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id++;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("shared_pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString(Integer.toString(id), etName.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getSharedPreferences("shared_pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private String UName;
    private String iName;
    private ListView lvName;
    private Button btnBack;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        lvName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNames);
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lvName.setAdapter(adapter);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String,String> names = (Map<String, String>) sharedPreferences.getAll();

        if(names != null){
            for(String value: names.values()){
                list.add(value);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```